# AS3 set focus on specific component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have a form with several component: datagrid, textArea, text input...
For each component FocusIn Event is available.

```
var objTarget:String;
     protected function memo_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
            {
                objTarget=event.currentTarget.id;       
}
```

With memo_focusInHandler, I know which has focus.

My goal is to backup last focus objet, and re open Windows with focus on this object.
I try to do this:

```
objTarget.setfocus();
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help to found the best way to reach my goal.

Comment: Just change `objTarget:String` to `objTarget:Object` and then loose the id property:  `objTarget = event.currentTarget`.  Then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need (that you've shown) to work with the string id reference.  It would much simpler (and slightly more efficient) to work directly with the object reference.

```
var objTarget:Object; // Object instead of type :String

protected function memo_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void {
    objTarget = event.currentTarget;  //instead of the currentTarget's id property, assign the current target itself       
}
```

Then, when you want to reset focus, you can do:

```
if(objTarget is TextInput || objTarget is TextArea){  //make sure it's a text input or text area first - optional but recommended if you don't like errors
    objTarget.selectRange(objTarget.text.length, objTarget.text.length); //set cursor to the end
    objTarget.setFocus(); //focus the text input/area
}
```

Answer (score 4):

String is not a display object, thus it can't be in `focus`. The representation of string on the stage is a TextField.

In as3 you can set focus to the desired target by using stage method:

```
stage.focus = myTarget;
```

Please see the corresponding documentation section: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
this[objTarget].selectRange(this[objTarget].text.length, this[objTarget].text.length);
    
    this[objTarget].setFocus();
```